# Asymptotic behavior of solutions of stochastic differential equations

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am studying a risk model whose dynamic is specified by a first order differential equation with a compound Poisson process on the right hand side. I would like to know whether there are some papers which describe the behavior of the process when time tends to infinity. In particular, I would like to know whether the process approaches $-\infty$ when time tends to $\infty$. I think that this question might be answered by papers on the asymptotic behavior of the solutions of stochastic differential equations. But I did not find satisfactory papers so far, since most related publications concentrate on the stability of the solutions. I would highly appreciate if some friends can give my kind help.

Comment: I have tried to improve the formulation of the post -- though I am not working on the field, so please check whether it reads o.k. now.

Comment: "I think that this question might be answered by papers on the asymptotic behavior of the solutions of stochastic differential equations. But I did not find satisfactory papers so far". In other words, you failed to find what you needed even though you knew *exactly* what you needed. To hope that somebody save the most erudite expert will find anything relevant from the general vague description you posted is a bit strange under such circumstances. Why don't you post the exact equation and tell the exact problem?

Comment: @ randalxu - From what I read you are either looking for reference on the recurrence/transience of the process or asymptotic stationary property. For the first, I think the book from Applebaum - Lévy Processes and Stochastic Calculus should do the trick, for the second subject re-check the web with this in mind. Regards

Comment: Dear Stefan, Fedja and The Bridge, thank you very much.